# Compare two objects on selected fields in C#

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

Code (that might potentially be pseudocode):

```
Person p1 = new Person { First = "John", Last = "Smith" };
Person p2 = new Person { First = "Jane", Last = "Smith" };
```

I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
bool b1 = Person.CompareOn({"First", "Last"}, p1, p2) // false;
bool b2 = Person.CompareOn({"Last"}         , p1, p2) // true;
```

Is there a predefined method that does this? Or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to specify the property names as strings rather than directly?

You could write your own custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151) implementation which takes a projection - and then also give it an `AndAlso` method to take another projection. I have the first part in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) and the rest shouldn't be too hard to use.

You'd use it something like this:

```
// The first argument here is only for the sake of type inference
var comparer = PropertyEqualityComparer.WithExample(p1, p => p.First)
                                       .AndAlso(p => p.Last);
bool equal = comparer.Equals(p1, p2);
```

or:

```
var comparer = PropertyEqualityComparer<Person>.Create(p1, p => p.First)
                                               .AndAlso(p => p.Last);
bool equal = comparer.Equals(p1, p2);
```

Unfortunately you can't use `params` here as you may well want each projection to have a different target type.

(You'd want to create one comparer for each scenario if possible.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Person class :

```
public virtual bool Equals(Person obj){
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (Equals(First, obj.First) == false) return false;
        if (Equals(Last, obj.Last) == false) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Then you can say :

```
 if(person1.Equals(person2){
                    blah....
}
```

Comment: You've missed the fact that there are two different comparisons required here - sometimes just on Last, sometimes on Last and First.

Comment: Except that he wants to be able to specify whether to compare on first name or not which your code doesn't allow...

Answer (score 0):

every class in C# derived from the main class: Object, and this have a method: equals(Object ), wich do the job. Is that method you should override

```
class Person {
     ...
     public bool Equals(Object o) {
          return (Person)o.LastName.Equals(this.LastName);
     }
 }
```

In the example, you should check if "o" is null or not, i'm checking for equals using lastname.